# Why Is It Possible to Loop Through a Null Array

Tags: powershell

Given the following PowerShell code:

```
$FolderItems = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test"

Write-Host "FolderItems Is Null: $($FolderItems -eq $null)"

foreach ($FolderItem in $FolderItems)
{
    Write-Host "Inside the loop: $($FolderItem.Name)"
}

Write-Host "Done."
```

When I test it with one file in the `C:\Test` folder, it outputs this:

```
FolderItems Is Null: False
Inside the loop: MyFile.txt
Done.
```

However, when I test it with ZERO files in the folder, it outputs this:

```
FolderItems Is Null: True
Inside the loop: 
Done."
```

If `$FolderItems` is null, then why does it enter the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an intentional design choice made in V1 and revisited in V3.

In most languages, the foreach statement can only loop over collections of things.  PowerShell has always been a little different, and in V1, you could loop over a single value in addition to collections of values.

For example:

```
foreach ($i in 42) { $i }  # prints 42
```

In V1, if a value was a collection, foreach would iterate over each element in the collection, otherwise it would enter the loop for just that value.

Note in the above sentence, $null isn't special.  It's just another value.  From a language design point of view, this is fairly clean and concisely explained.

Unfortunately many people did not expect this behavior and it caused many bugs.  I think some confusion arises because people expect the foreach statement to behave almost like the foreach-object cmdlet.  In other words, I think people expect the following to work the same:

```
$null | foreach { $_ }
foreach ($i in $null) { $i }
```

In V3, we decided that it was important enough to change behavior because we could help scripters avoid introducing bugs in their scripts.

Note that changing the behavior could in theory break existing scripts in unexpected ways.  We ultimately decided that most scripts that potentially see $null in the foreach statement already guard the foreach statement with an if, e.g.:

```
if ($null -ne $c)
{
    foreach ($i in $c) { ... }
}
```

So in reality, most real world scripts would not see a change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This was something of an idiosyncracy/bug in ForEach in V1 and V2.  It was corrected in the V3 release.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me like you need to wrap your `foreach` within a conditional that checks if `$FolderItem != null`. This way, it'll never get in the `if` statement whenever `$FolderItems` is `NULL`

```
If (-NOT $FolderItems -eq $null) {
    foreach ($FolderItem in $FolderItems)
    {
        Write-Host "Inside the loop: $($FolderItem.Name)"
    }
}
```

This may be of help as well http://bit.ly/1brKRRk

Comment: Was OP not asking *why* it happens? Not *how* to avoid it?

Comment: Yes, I know how to avoid it.